# PySpark - Add map function as column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a pyspark DataFrame

```python
a = [
    ('Bob', 562),
    ('Bob',880),
    ('Bob',380),
    ('Sue',85),
    ('Sue',963)
] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, ["Person", "Amount"])
```

I need to create a column that hashes the `Amount` and returns the amount. The problem is I can't use a `UDF` so I have used a mapping function.

```python
df.rdd.map(lambda x: hash(x["Amount"]))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can't use `udf` you can use the `map` function, but as you've currently written it, there will only be one column. To keep all the columns, do the following:

```python
df = df.rdd\
    .map(lambda x: (x["Person"], x["Amount"], hash(str(x["Amount"]))))\
    .toDF(["Person", "Amount", "Hash"])

df.show()
#+------+------+--------------------+
#|Person|Amount|                Hash|
#+------+------+--------------------+
#|   Bob|   562|-4340709941618811062|
#|   Bob|   880|-7718876479167384701|
#|   Bob|   380|-2088598916611095344|
#|   Sue|    85|    7168043064064671|
#|   Sue|   963|-8844931991662242457|
#+------+------+--------------------+
```

**Note**: In this case, `hash(x["Amount"])` is not very interesting so I changed it to hash `Amount` converted to a string.

Essentially you have to map the row to a tuple containing all of the existing columns and add in the new column(s).

If your columns are too many to enumerate, you could also just add a tuple to the existing row.

```python
df = df.rdd\
    .map(lambda x: x + (hash(str(x["Amount"])),))\
    .toDF(df.columns + ["Hash"])\
```

---

I should also point out that if hashing the values is your end goal, there is also a pyspark function [`pyspark.sql.functions.hash`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hash) that can be used to avoid the serialization to `rdd`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn("Hash", f.hash("Amount")).show()
#+------+------+----------+
#|Person|Amount|      Hash|
#+------+------+----------+
#|   Bob|   562|  51343841|
#|   Bob|   880|1241753636|
#|   Bob|   380| 514174926|
#|   Sue|    85|1944150283|
#|   Sue|   963|1665082423|
#+------+------+----------+
```

This appears to use a different hashing algorithm than the python builtin.